# What does "four years in advance of the last fifty" mean?

Tags: meaning

In a speech given by Lucy Stone called "The Progress of Fifty Years" in 1893, she says, "Four years in advance of the last fifty, in 1833, Oberlin College, in Ohio, was founded. Its charter declared its grand object, 'To give the most useful education at the least expense of health, time, and money.'"

If the speech was delivered in 1893, how could "four years in advance of the last fifty" be referring to 1833?

Comment: Had she been drinking when she said this? Or maybe arithmetic wasn't her strong suit.

Comment: Four years in advance of the last fifty means 54 years ago. If the speech was delivered in 1893, four years in advance of the last fifty would refer to 1839. The math doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm guessing the speech was written earlier.

Comment: It would also make sense if the Oberlin college ceased to exist in 1887, if it was founded in 1837 and then shut down 50 years later. In 1832, 4 years before it was founded, something was declared. And "the last fifty" would be the "the last fifty years of its existence."

Comment: @JasonBassford - Except that nothing like that is true.

Comment: The speech she gave was in 1893 but she could have been referring to an event recently mentioned. A fuller context might reveal she had been discussing an event of 1887.

Comment: Wikipedia: In 1835 Oberlin became one of the first colleges in the United States to admit African Americans, and *in 1837 the first to admit women* (other than Franklin College's brief experiment in the 1780s). The numbers still don't make sense though. @HotLicks is probably right, as usual.

Answer (score 2):

The full text of the speech can be found at [Women's History Guide](http://womenshistory.info/progress-fifty-years/).

A clue to the use of "the last fifty" can be found in a line that is read later on (emphasis mine):

> **Half a century ago** women were at an infinite disadvantage in regard to their occupations. The idea that their sphere was at home, and only at home, was like a band of steel on society. But the spinning-wheel and the loom, which had given employment to women, had been superseded by machinery, and something else had to take their places.

This suggests two things. First, she was not referring to the last fifty years of the college, but to the last fifty years of advancement of women's equality.

Also, rather than being exact and writing *fifty-six years*, she wrote *fifty years* as an abbreviated way of referring to  *half a century*, words which she actually used later on.

It's not precise, mathematically, but it seems she wasn't attempting to be precise.

Comment: The speech, which her Wikipedia page confirms was given in 1893, may be a transcript; could she have said “for” instead of “four”?  She often emphasizes the importance ofnearly schools committed to educating women.

Comment: @Xanne The use of *for* would certainly make at least as much sense, if not more.